# Sticky footer containing multiple divs not working

Tags: css, html, footer, sticky

I'm really struggling with my footer. I've followed the instructions at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ to make my footer stick to the bottom of the page. It works fine until I add divs into the footer div - the purple background and image disappears. I would do it as a single div but I can't work out how to do the zigzag edge without creating a separate box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been trying for days to get this to work.
Here is my HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">


     <!-- Begin Header -->
     <div id="header">

    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" width="435px" height="112px" alt="Lauren Womack Logo" /></a>

    <div id="menu">
    <a href="/"><img src="images/menu/home.png" width="142" height="160" alt="Home"  /></a> 
    <a href="about.html"><img src="images/menu/about.png" width="131" height="157" alt="About"  /></a>
    <a href="contact.html"><img src="images/menu/contact.png" width="128" height="160" alt="Contact"  /></a>     
    </div>             
    </div>
     <!-- End Header -->
     <!-- Begin Content -->
     <div id="content">
    <div id="rightholder">
    <div class="outerleft">
    <div class="inner"><h2>Animation and Interactive</h2>
    </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="outerright">
    <div class="inner">
    <h2>Web Design</h2>
    </div>       
    </div>
    <div class="outerleft">
    <div class="inner">
    <h2>Print Design</h2>
</div></div>

    <div class="outerright">
    <div class="inner">
    <h2>Illustration</h2>
</div>   
       </div></div>          <!-- End Content -->
    </div>
    </div><!-- Begin Footer -->   
    <div id="footer">
    <div class="footeredge">  </div>
    <div class="footerinner">     <p>© Lauren Womack 2012</p>
    </div>        </div>   </div>
            <!-- End Footer --></body></html>
```

And here's my css:

```
    body {font-size: 13px; background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; height: 100%;}
    html {height: 100%;}
    #wrapper{ min-height:100%; min-width:992px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;}
    #header {height: 170px; padding-top:36px; border: none;}
    #menu {float:right;}
    #content { position: relative; min-width: 1141px; border:none;background: none; overflow:auto; padding-right:32px; padding-left:32px; padding-bottom: 86px;}
    #rightholder { float: right; clear: left;min-width: 639px;width: 60%;padding-top: 90px;}
    .outerright {background-image:url(images/threadborder.jpg);min-width: 257px;width: 45%; height: 98px; margin-top: 22px; margin-bottom: 22px; margin-left: 20px;float: right;clear: right;}
    .outerleft {background-image:url(images/threadborder.jpg);
min-width: 257px; width: 45%; height: 98px; margin-top: 22px;margin-bottom: 22px;margin-right: 20px; float: left;clear: left;}
    .inner {padding: 5px; height: 87px;}
    #footer {position: relative; margin-top:-86px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; height:86px; clear:both; padding-right: 32px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; border: none;
    /*Opera Fix*/
    body:before {
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;/
    }
    .footeredge {
background-color: none;
background-image:url(images/footer/zigzag.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height: 20px;
    }
    .footerinner {
background-color:#663366;
height: 66px;
    }
```

How I want it to look: http://tinypic.com/r/242swuc/6 The purple box at the bottom and the zigzag isn't showing though, just the text.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a jsfiddle, or link to an environment where this is hosted?

Comment: http://laurenwomack.com/laurenwomack.com/ Just managed to upload it.

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no closing curly brace for #footer, which in turn break's your style declarations after this point.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I'm glad it's something so simple as well.